Getting "Run Error Index:1, Size: 1" upon running pandas.read_csv() in Jupyter notebook
Using Jupyter notebook in IntelliJ with Python 3.11
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('customers-100.csv')

Tried using different csv files and with additional arguments such as:
df = pd.read_csv('customers-100.csv', header=None)
df = pd.read_csv('customers-100.csv', index_col=0)

Link to csv files:
customers-100.csv
zomato.csv
Error message: "Run Error Index:1, Size: 1"

linking to files is not desired since the link may change or disappear over time

It fixed itself once I restarted IntelliJ and Jupyter kernel. Wasted almost 2hrs on this crap.
